# how to use different docker images for running scripts per stage?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Starting from a .gitlab-ci.yml like so:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - stage1
  - stage2

doStage1:
  stage: stage1
script:
  - docker build -t <container> .
  - docker push <container>
only:
  - master

doStage2:
  stage: stage2
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    script:
     - cat /etc/os-release
only:
  - master
```

I would have expected that stage2 is ran on an alpine docker image but is not, the output of cat command is showing me:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.4 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

which is the gitlab runner os, what am I misunderstanding here? from gitlab ci docs says that we can use different docker images per stage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is interested on this issue, finally I figured out what was happening. The gitlab runner was configured with **shell** executor instead of **docker** executor ence it wasn't able to process image: property.

I provisioned another runner with docker executor and everything worked as expected.